# SQL: Casting text to date

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a TEXT column of dates and need to convert them to dates, but the two methods I'm using are not working correctly. See below.

```html
SELECT CAST("12/01/2009" as date);
12
```

This only returns the first digit before stoping at the '/'.

```html
SELECT DATE("12/01/2009");
Returns nothing
```

I also tried CONVERT, but I'm using SQLite and it doesn't appear to support it as I'm getting a syntax error. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Don't use double quotes. Try `SELECT CAST('12/01/2009' as Date)` instead.

Comment: best way is to use `2009-12-01` format (year-month-day). `12/01/2009` is it first December or 12th January?

Comment: Ken, I tried that too. I'm using SQLite if that makes a difference. Getting same response.

Comment: It's currently in mdY format

Comment: It certainly makes a difference, especially when you tag it with **mySQL**. Please use tags that actually are relevant to your question, and don't just grab tags that contain words or phrases or letters that look familiar. It's a waste of both your time and ours when you add irrelevant tags to your post, as you don't get an answer as quickly and we waste our time providing information related to something other than what you're really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('12/01/2009','%m/%d/%Y');
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/38058)**

Comment: SELECT STR_TO_DATE('12/01/2009','%m/%d/%Y');
Error: no such function: STR_TO_DATE
I"m using SQLite3

Comment: @FranciscoCervera - Then you should tag `Sqlite` not `Mysql`

Comment: Ok this worked. I tried it without sqlite. Sorry. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SqLite doesn't have date type. You need to do string manipulation do achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CAST('2009-01-12' AS DATE);
```

Use it.
It returns 2014-02-28